# Does conan package creation default pass -Werror flag?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-warnings, vtk, conan

tldr: Is the compiler -Werrror flag passed by default in conan 1.29? How can you avoid passing it?

After updating apple-clang to 12.0 and conan to 1.29.2, I can no longer build a custom VTK conan package I've used for at least 6 months. I have no problem building the full VTK 9.0.1 using the default cmake setup that comes with the source. But for my conan build I now get the following build error which looks like it's caused by a -Werror flag forcing a warning into an error. Is this normally just a warning and, if so how can I turn off the -Werror flag for conan builds?

```
ThirdParty/hdf5/vtkhdf5/src/H5Fsuper.c:1397:16: error: 
  implicit declaration of function 'vtkhdf5_H5O__fsinfo_set_version' is invalid in C99
  [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        if(H5O__fsinfo_set_version(f, &fsinfo) < 0)
           ^

ThirdParty/hdf5/vtkhdf5/src/vtk_hdf5_mangle.h:1882:33: note: 
  expanded from macro 'H5O__fsinfo_set_version'
#define H5O__fsinfo_set_version vtkhdf5_H5O__fsinfo_set_version
```

Comment: "Is the compiler -Werrror flag passed by default in conan 1.29?" - It is very unlikely that Conan or other build system *automatically* passes `-Werror` flag. But look carefully into the error message: it tells about unkown ("implicit declaration") function `vtkhdf5_H5O__fsinfo_set_version`. This would hardly work **even without** `-Werror`. So the problem is somewhere else...

Comment: I hit the exact same error today on OSX. Nothing whatsoever to do with conan, but I have been shuffling around dependencies in a conda environment. Baffled. 

Comment: maybe some issue with local system HDF5 being linked

Comment: I'm still convinced the conan cmake configuration is causing bad linking. VTK itself builds fine, but this minimal conan packaging reproduces the error for apple-clang 12, but builds fine on gcc:

https://github.com/divergentscott/conan-vtk/blob/master/conanfile.py

@taranaki are you building VTK with their standard included CMakeLists?

Comment: Kitware is aware of the bug https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/-/issues/18056